# I need to sample 8 audio sources at audio quality, what MCU can I use?

Tags: microcontroller, audio, adc, sampling

I need to sample 8 audio sources at the same time, at a decent frequency (say, 40Khz). Being only familiar with Arduino, I searched online for tutorials and articles about using interfacing it with ADC chips, such as the MCP3008. What I found out is that the arduino is definitely too slow for sampling 8 sources at the same time, since it can only get up to 58Khz when sampling a single signal (according to [this](https://rheingoldheavy.com/mcp3008-tutorial-05-sampling-audio-frequency-signals-02/) site)

What I wanted to ask you is: what MCUs do I need to look at if I want to sample 8 sources at the same time? I also need to do other stuff with the signals as well, once they are sampled (mostly mixing them, digitally of course).

Thank you!

Comment: What's "audio quality" in bits per sample? 8 "sources" = 8 channels?

Comment: @HannoBinder: Let's assume "CD-quality" audio: 16 bits per sample, 44.1 kHz (or maybe 48 kHz) sample rate. We would still need to know whether a "source" is mono or stereo.

Comment: And what should happen to the samples? Just read and discard? Read and forward to another chip, SD card, ...? Read, average values, turn on LED?

Answer (score 1):

I'll give a generic answer, since specific recommendations are off-topic for this site.

You should be looking at 16-bit DSP chips, such as those from Analog Devices or Microchip (the ones I most often work with), since these have both the I/O interfaces that you need and the computing horsepower to process the data streams in real time.

For that many channels, you're unlikely to find a single-chip solution; instead, you'll be using external codecs (A/D and D/A converters) connected to the DSP via something like I2S.

Answer (score 0):

something like [this](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/microcontrollers_16-bit_32-bit/c2000_performance/real-time_control/f2802x_f2803x_f2806x/overview.page) for example. Check for enough ADC channels and the like. Welcome to the real world
(I quote the matrix, as almost anything µC related today has moved to 16 bit microcontrollers. The exception of course is university courses and arduino)